# LLVM and Clang installation

Tags: windows, compilation

I recently installed LLVM and Clang on my machine running windows 7. It also has cygwin installed. I went to the [this URL](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt2/) and followed the instructions in Part 1 and Part 2. I installed MinGW for both 32 bits and 64 bits. However, I do not have the directory `C:\mingw64` and I do not have the directory `C:\mingw32`. I do have a directory called `C:\mingw` and off of that I do have a directory `mingw32`.

I saved the two `.bat` files `setgcc32` and `setgcc64` on the page and ran them. When I try the following command line in 32 bit mode:

```
clang++  main.cpp -o main.exe -std=c++14
```

I get:

```
c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I try it in 64 bit mode, I get:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
 ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run this command:

```
   clang++  -v main.cpp -o main.exe -std=c++14
```

in 32 bit mode, I get:

```
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/rc3)
Target: i686-pc-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-windows-
gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-mo
del static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mc
onstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir "C:\
\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.7.0" -internal-isystem "c:\\R
tools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\
\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem
"c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isys
tem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\4.6.3" -internal-isy
stem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\4.6.3\\i686-w64-min
gw32" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\
4.6.3\\backward" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\include\\c++\\4.6.3"
-internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\include\\c++\\4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32"
 -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\include\\c++\\4.6.3\\backward" -inter
nal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\include\\
c++" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3
\\include\\c++\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\
\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isystem "C:\\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.7.0\\include" -internal-isystem
"c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\include" -internal-is
ystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include" -internal
-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\include-fixe
d" -internal-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include" -interna
l-isystem "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\include" -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug
-compilation-dir "C:\\tmp6" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -mstackrealign
-fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnosti
cs-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o "C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mai
n-fdf675.o" -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0-rc3 default target i686-pc-window
s-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
\4.6.3"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
\4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++
\4.6.3\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.6
.3\include\c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.6
.3\include\c++\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.6
.3\include\c++\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mi
ngw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\include\c++\4.6.3
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\include\c++\4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\include\c++\4.6.3\backward
 C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.0\include
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.6.3\include
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.6.3\include-fixed
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include
 c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\include
End of search list.
 "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin\\ld.exe" -m i386pe -Bdynamic -o main.exe "c:\\Rtool
s\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\lib\\crt2.o" "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i
686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\crtbegin.o" "-Lc:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64
-mingw32\\4.6.3" "-Lc:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32\\lib" "-Lc:\\Rtools\
\gcc-4.6.3\\lib" "-Lc:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib"
"C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-fdf675.o" -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s
 -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -l
mingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\lib\
\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\4.6.3\\crtend.o"
c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invoca
tion)
```

Comment: try using `clang++ -v` to see what search paths and steps the compiler does.

Comment: Not related to the programming languages.

Comment: If you're including stdio.h into a C++ program, you should be doing `#include <cstdio>`